# Add a sticky view underneath the Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7

I've seen a few other examples, but I haven't seen anything that actually sticks. What I want is essentially what a tableViewHeader does. I have a tableViewController with a navigation bar. I want to put a view into place that shows some search criteria in a small bar directly below the navbar. But I need it to stick when the user swipes to view the results.

I've tried adding a UIView as a subview to the navigation bar, but it always sits at the top of the Navigation Bar, overlaying everything.

Comment: Why not use top layout guide and set the view's top to the topLayoutGuide.bottom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what worked:

```
// Create a custom navigation view
    _navigationView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    _navigationView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    _navigationView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f,
                                       self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.origin.y + 44.0f,
                                       self.view.frame.size.width,
                                       30.0f);

    // Create bottom border for the custom navigation view
    _navigationViewBorder = [[UIView alloc] init];
    _navigationViewBorder.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    _navigationViewBorder.tag = 1;
    _navigationViewBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f,
                                             self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.origin.y + 74.0f,
                                             self.view.frame.size.width,
                                             0.5f);

    // Add labels for date, results, and the time range
    _dateDisplay = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 70, 15)];
    [_dateDisplay setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:13]];
    [_dateDisplay setText:@""];

    _timeRangeDisplay = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(98, 0, 135, 15)];
    [_timeRangeDisplay setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:13]];
    [_timeRangeDisplay setText:@""];

    _resultsDisplay = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240, 0, 80, 15)];
    [_resultsDisplay setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:13]];
    [_resultsDisplay setText:@""];

    [_navigationView addSubview: _dateDisplay];
    [_navigationView addSubview: _timeRangeDisplay];
    [_navigationView addSubview: _resultsDisplay];

    // Add two views to the navigation bar
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar.superview insertSubview:_navigationView belowSubview:self.navigationController.navigationBar];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar.superview insertSubview:_navigationViewBorder belowSubview:_navigationView];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not add the view to your viewController's view, and set up its constraints so that it sits just below the navigationBar, but above the tableView?

If it's only supposed to be there some of the time, you can animate its constraints to show/hide it.

Comment: I added it via [self.view addSubview] but it didn't stick. I assume because this is a tableViewController, not a ViewController with a tableView in it.

Comment: Ahhh, I missed that detail, my apologies. If you were to use a UIViewController with a UITableView property then you might have a bit more control over the view hierarchy etc. Using a UITableViewController, I'm pretty sure that self.view is actually the tableView. So you may need to convert to a normal UIViewController to achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: You can use `setContentInset` on the `tableView` to move it down and then insert a view with your required controls in that free space you will have by moving the table view down.