# Shadow discoloring the navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift3

The shadow is appearing on top of the navigation bar. Is there anyway to move the shadow underneath the bar or add some code so it doesn't discolor the bar?

This is the code I use in my navigation controller:

```
    import UIKit

    class navigationController:UINavigationController, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate{


    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        var appblue = UIColor(red: 109/255, green: 208/255, blue:247/255, alpha: 1.0)
        self.navigationBar.barTintColor = appblue
        self.navigationBar.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.navigationBar.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.navigationBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
        self.navigationBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2.0)
        self.navigationBar.layer.shadowRadius = 4
    }
}
```

and this is what it looks like:

[image]

When it should be this color:

[image]

Any suggestions?

This is what im trying to make it look like(photo shopped picture):
(the top bar bottom shadow while retaining the second bars color)
[image]

Comment: in your VC embed with Navigation controller

Comment: your code also correct and fine , just add `self.navigationController?. navigationBar ` in  `self.navigationBar`

Comment: The viewDidLoad() function above is in a separate navigation controller class not in each view controller class.

Comment: can you attach ur project

Comment: I updated my question with the whole navigation class to show the way I have it set up. I then set each of the navigation controllers in the storyboard to use that class

Comment: hide these two lines ` var appblue = UIColor(red: 109/255, green: 208/255, blue:247/255, alpha: 1.0)
        self.navigationBar.barTintColor = appblue`

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39232497/iosadd-view-below-navigation-bar-across-viewcontrollers

Comment: this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26102474/add-a-sticky-view-underneath-the-navigation-bar

Answer (score 0):

Added a image view with a gradient to the bottom of the bar to accomplish what I was going for, Thanks to @Anbu.Karthik for linking another question that I was able to adapt. This is my current code:

```
import UIKit

class navigationController:UINavigationController, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate{

override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        var appblue = UIColor(red: 109/255, green: 208/255, blue:247/255, alpha: 1.0)
        self.navigationBar.barTintColor = appblue
        self.navigationBar.layer.masksToBounds = false

        var yPosition = self.navigationBar.layer.frame.height
        var rectWidth = self.navigationBar.layer.frame.width
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        let bottomShadow: UIImageView = UIImageView()
        bottomShadow.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: yPosition, width: rectWidth, height: 8)
        gradient.frame = bottomShadow.bounds
        gradient.colors = [UIColor.lightGray.cgColor, UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0).cgColor]

        navigationBar.addSubview(bottomShadow)
        bottomShadow.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    }
}
```